# How to find the device color in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to find the color of an Android device. I am able to find all details of device regarding its OS, battery, etc. but how can I find its color?

If android does not provide the color of device can any one tell the reason behind it? On iPhone it is possible to detect the color of device so why not on Android?

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is no such API in Android so far. Because unlike Iphone, Threre are different manufactures who make Android devices. Android runs in different types of devices. It doesn't even have to be a mobile phone. In fact none of these reasons make it impossible but it simply is not worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is not manufactured into one factory. The phone could be assembled in a factory but all parts may be generated into other companies. Processor, battery, and others are produced in their own factory. In the same way, its cover also produced a different factory. Some factories provide SDK to get info about devices like battery factory gives a way to get its current percentage, overall capacity and etc. But it will not give way to detect its color. Since you may change it any color battery. In the same way, you may frequently change your cover with any color you want. Some covers are really made by plastic and there is no way to get its color. That is why manufacturers do not want to put effort to detect the device color